# My Laravel application load time is very slow

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-5, boot

My Laravel application loading time is in seconds not in milli-seconds how to I make it fast
Can any one help it would be useful.
Thanks in advance!

Image of the load time:
[image: Image of the load time]